# I can't initialize the MutableListOf() on onCreate

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, inheritance, initialization, mutablelist

```
class PostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var firestoreDb : FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var posts : MutableList<Post>
    private lateinit var adapter: PostAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post)

        posts = mutableListOf()  // I can't access mutableListOf()
```

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PyPU.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F94ko.png)

I can't reach the `mutableListOf()` extension under `onCreate`, but it can in the example video I watched. I tried invalidates and restart -> Clean build project.

[*screenshot 3*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCvZN.jpg)

they can access it here but i can't. How can I solve this problem ? Please help

Comment: plesae help me guys

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Make sure your Kotlin plug-in is up to date and make sure your project’s build.gradle specifies that same plugin version. Unrelated to your question but there’s no reason you should be using lateinit for a list that starts empty.

Comment: thanks I will try update

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when initializing:

```kotlin
private val posts : MutableList<Post> = mutableListOf()
```